# Which grind should be used for brewing coffee without machine?

Tags: beans

I use this method https://cookingcrest.com/prepare-filter-coffee-without-coffee-filter/

Following are the options of selecting grinds:
[image]

Which one should be chosen?

Comment: Why do you think coffee made with French press will be better than the manual method, please explain? @avocado1

Comment: I can write more the next days, but in short this recipe is super complex, uses lots of different vessels just to make a simple turkish style coffee (why do they keep pouring it in new cups? It makes literally no sense at all.). With a French press you can make better coffee with much less work. This is the main reason. Keep things simple. Other than that there's plenty else that could be improved. Like e.g. you shouldn't literally boil coffee nor milk as I mentioned earlier, you usually don't froth the coffee but just the milk, you first froth and in the end add sugar to taste.

Comment: A lot of the steps taken here make the beverage in the end bitter, which makes it necessary to add sugar. Milk is naturally sweet if you don't destroy it by boiling it. Coffee that's brewed too hot becomes bitter as well, encouraging the use of sugar. In the end you have to add so much sugar to the coffee that all the health benefits of coffee for example just vanish. I realize that this is probably a cultural thing, so maybe "wrong" is too harsh a criticism. In the end it's a matter of taste and preference. If you like your coffee like this there is nothing inherently "wrong" with it.

Comment: The facts remain though, that this method makes unnecessary bitter coffee that has to be balanced by adding sugar. Also that it makes a lot of steps that can be avoided by using a simple filter method like French Press (with an extra cup to froth the milk or, if you really want to, the milk-coffee-sugar mixture).

Comment: @avocado1 I think your first comment is a bit harsh. You should never forget that others may actually like what your deem inferior. Consider different cultures and traditions.

Answer (score 1):

The explained methodology is traditional Indian-style preparation method.

As far as I know, historically Indians realize that tea and coffee includes many active radicals at the early ages just by observation. (I'm skeptical that it is related to any chemical knowledge.) Then, they started to add milk to these two beverages to neutralize the radical components. That's why Indians have this kind of coffee as well as *Chai Latte*.

This method may seem similar to Turkish method in the beginning of decoction, but requires much more brewing time. Mostly ended up warm, if not cold, mixed with lots of milk and sugar.

You can watch how this coffee is prepared in [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=F_8zIJgPOOk).

Finally, *which grind is best for this type of coffee?*

As this is kind of decoction, Turkish grind seems like the first option. But, brewing will take longer. So, **I opt for Mokka grind**.

---

*Edit:* I realized that, the list actually includes **South Indian Filter** method. So, please choose that option. This option is normally very rare in the rest of the globe. That's probably why I missed that.

Answer (score 0):

The method seems to be similar to Turkish coffee and calls for coffee powder. So I’ll assume Turkish grind will work well.

However, fresh ground coffee only stays fresh for very few hours so you might want to get a grinder eventually, preferably a burr grinder. If you are a regular coffee drinker, the cost of coffee beans + milk will soon surpass the cost of any consumer level coffee equipments.